# Design Bug: Preview of links mismatches actual links

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If you type in a link in the Edit box, the preview pane shows the link in bold.

When you save it, the actual site shows it underlined.

Comment: I noticed that too, pretty weird

Comment: looking into it. thanks.

Comment: I thought I was just losing it when I saw this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be fixed in the latest build.

Please see the attached screenshots.
I'm not able to reproduce this issue.

[image: Main site]

[image: meta site]

Comment: It's still not fixed, can you check?

Comment: Just checked this out - are you guys still seeing this issue?

Comment: Seems fixed now, thanks Sean.