# Links in preview inconsistent with final

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design Bug: Preview of links mismatches actual links](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/design-bug-preview-of-links-mismatches-actual-links)

Actual links in the question are underlined. However while in preview mode, they are not. Since with current design both normal text and links are same color it's rather hard to see them.

Comment: Still waiting for the fix to be delivered...